# ~90 GB missing after extending partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I needed more space for my Windows partition.

My solution was to remove the BTRFS partition from the disk that contains the Windows partition so that the partition can be easily extended. **This freed up around 90 GB on the disk. Once done, the Windows partition was extended to include the 90 GB.

On booting into Windows the disk size... is the same. Still only 20 GB free.**

[One suggestion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-does-not-recognize-full-partition-size/99045930-948e-4ac1-8eae-737245beacd0) is to shrink the partition and extend it again. I shrank the partition but only by 17 GB because that's all Windows offered.

[image: Disk Management]

I extended the partition again but it makes no difference.

`chkdsk` reports no issues. I ran an "optimise" (discard) but it made no difference.

I have 90 GB missing and no idea how to solve it.

---

**Note**: Extending a partition of any type does not and will not affect the size of the disk, nor does it affect the size reported by Windows. Partitions are NOT disks.

The partition table is a standard MBR:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb print
Model: ATA TOSHIBA THNSNJ25 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  608MB  607MB   primary  ntfs
 2      608MB   254GB  253GB   primary  ntfs
 4      254GB   256GB  2147MB  primary  ext4         boot
```

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -lx /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA THNSNJ25
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00541412

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors Id Type            Start-C/H/S   End-C/H/S Attrs
/dev/sdb1            2048   1187839   1185792  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT     0/32/33   73/239/38 
/dev/sdb2         1187840 495919103 494731264  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT   73/239/39 1023/254/63 
/dev/sdb4  *    495921152 500115455   4194304 83 Linux           1023/254/63 1023/254/63    80
```

Also checked that the resize completely correctly (i.e. no slack space):

```
$ sudo ntfsresize -vxn /dev/sdb2
ntfsresize v2021.8.22 (libntfs-3g)
Sectors allocated to volume :  old 494731256 current 494731256 difference 0
Clusters allocated to volume : old 61841407 current 61841407 difference 0
ERROR: Cannot expand volume : the partition has not been expanded
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150838/discussion-on-question-by-ken-sharp-90-gb-missing-after-extending-partition); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Can we see *entire* disk management window pls? Windows not seeing free space once volume is resized is file system issue, which are sort of unrelated to partition sizes which is about all you're showing us.

Answer (score 0):

1. This seems like a [known issue](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-kb5034441-security-update-fails-with-0x80070643-errors/): "[P]art of Microsoft's January 2024 Patch Tuesday, a security update (KB5034441) was released... However, when attempting to install this update, Windows 10 users are reporting getting 0x80070643 errors and the installation failing... when the Windows Recovery Partition is not large enough."

   Microsoft likely is in the process of fixing the update, but offers advice on an immediate workaround, with the advice, "**Caution: these steps are complicated, and carry some risk. This is best done by *advanced users with experience* using the command line. If you make an error in entering these commands, you could put your device in a no-boot situation, and possibly lose data you have stored on the device.**"
2. Were all operations in diskmgmt.msc committed?
3. Add up all numbers. The drive shows as [~238.5 GB (binary) total capacity, which is ~256 GB (decimal)](https://www.kylesconverter.com/data-storage/gigabytes-to-gigabytes-(binary)). Is that not correct? Manufacturers like to quote disk size as a decimal number, i.e., power of 10, rather than binary, power of two, because it appears larger.

   - System: ~0.5 GB
   - Windows: ~218.5 GB
   - **Unallocated space**: ~17.5 GB
   - ~2 GB: Unnamed partition (Linux swap?)
   - The sum of above is 238.5 GB, just the drive total capacity, no space missing!

   However, you've 17.5 **unallocated**. Why? Windows cannot use that space unless it is made into a *formatted* partition for. You can do that with diskmgmt.msc (right-click, make a new simple volume, and format it as a recovery partition.

Finally, running Windows on a "256 GB" drive is like driving a pickup truck with [12" tires.](http://www.subcompactculture.com/2012/07/of-small-tires-and-economy-cars.html). Removing space to create a Linux partition aggravates the situation.

Comment: @KenSharp - You didn't specify which update was failing.

Comment: @Ramhound It's irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @KenSharp - I don't think you could possible make that determination.  After reading into the problems with KB5034441, I also suspect, your problem is directly linked to the WinRE being updated. If you will not provide something as simple, as the update you are trying to update, then I cannot even attempt to answer your question.

Comment: @KenSharp - Your screenshot shows no missing space. The sum of all allocated and unallocated partitions is the sum of your total space.

Comment: Partitions are not disks. Disks are not partitions. If you add 90GB to a partition it DOES NOT affect the size of a disk in any way. It SHOULD affect the size of the partition. I honestly cannot make it any more clear than this.

Comment: "Partitions are not disks. Disks are not partitions."  There's only one physical disk.  Using the entire disk space in one partition, that is a drive/partition.  But it's still seperate things, as you say.  They are ALL partitions.  Which are disks to an operating system, physical or not, it doesn't know or care.  GPT does not use an MBR.  If you delete a GPT partition that is "next to" the NTFS/FAT partition, the OS doesn't know or care.  It's not viewing it in a linear way.

Comment: There was no GPT partition but I really don't understand what you mean by the OS doesn't care. The only reason to delete the partition next to the NTFS partition is because it can be *easily* extended, otherwise you have to assign a new drive letter to it (on a basic disk). It is easily extended because Windows sees the disk space in a linear way. Dynamic disks are more useful but it came from factory as a basic disk. GPT really doesn't have anything to do with this. There's never been a GPT or a GPT partition on this disk since it was bought.

Comment: Yes, but you can only extend it *easily* if they are both MBR's.  The windows fdisk will never see the 90gb.  The GPT entry is cock blocking it.  You removed it, but you've just set the bits overwriteable.  It will never see it to overwrite.